# How to fix 'SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0' - POST null body

Tags: express, google-cloud-platform

I have a cloud function running Express to serve as a web hook endpoint.
My client sends a POST request with a null body value.
And the service returns 400 Bad Request with this log :

```
    SyntaxError: Unexpected token # in JSON at position 0
    at Object.parse (native)
    at createStrictSyntaxError (/var/tmp/worker/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:157:10)
    at parse (/var/tmp/worker/node_modules/body-parser/lib/types/json.js:83:15)
    at /var/tmp/worker/node_modules/body-parser/lib/read.js:121:18
    at invokeCallback (/var/tmp/worker/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:224:16)
    at done (/var/tmp/worker/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:213:7)
    at IncomingMessage.onEnd (/var/tmp/worker/node_modules/raw-body/index.js:273:7)
    at emitNone (events.js:86:13)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:978:12)
```

But null is a valid JSON value. Any other correct JSON value seems fine.

As more concrete exemples :

> response 200 :
>
> > curl -d '{"foo": true}' -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST {endpoint_url}
>
> response 400 / SyntaxError :
>
> > curl -d null -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X POST {endpoint_url}

Express doesn't seem to be reached, so I suppose the request is parsed and validated upfront?
How can I log the request to analyze why it is rejected?

thank you

Comment: Have you checked for some log registry on Stackdriver logs?

Answer (score 1):

If we look at the stack trace from the code, we find that it points to approximately [here](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser/blob/master/lib/types/json.js#L71) (source).  Reading that code, we then seem to find that the expected/required input data must be JSON that starts with either `{` (an object) or `[` (an array).  This would mean that `null` or even a scalar value would fail with the error described.

If we then look at the documentation of bodyParser found [here](https://github.com/expressjs/body-parser#bodyparserjsonoptions) we read about an option called `strict` which, when set to `true` instructs our parser to *only* accept objects or arrays while when `false` allows us to accept scalars too.  Since the default on `strict` is `true`, my assumption is that one can only pass in objects or arrays.

If this is the case, then sending in `null` would be an invalid / unsupported parameter.  It could be that if you need to send in a single scalar value, send it in as a value of a field in an object:

```
{
  "value": null
}
```

or as an element in an array

```
[null]
```